# Photo Competition 2021-04-26: All Blur

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: All Blur

In the spirit of [Why would one shoot a fully blurred picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17504/), let's see some abstract and semi-abstract works.

This theme was suggested by [mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm).

#### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on April 26, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that the "winners" of these are always among the first half dozen "answer" posts?  Perhaps we need to ask people not to vote for a few days to allow more equal voting...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Perhaps an open for submission time period, then closed. Then    an open for  voting time period.

Comment: @ZeissIkon What you have seen is common amongst all Stacks, where early answers tend to benefit from higher votes than later answers. And because these Photo Competition questions tend to end up on Hot Network Questions (HNQ), the effect is magnified. I don't know how asking people to hold off on voting would work in the Stack Exchange model. But these types of concerns are definitely worth opening up a topic dicussion in  [meta]

Comment: [Meta question on the voting for photo competitions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/how-can-we-improve-the-voting-on-the-photo-competitions)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Working Through the Night

April 12th 2021 1:30 AM, Los Gatos, CA

iPhone 7+, my keyboard, and solely my monitor/keyboard backlight used for lighting

Swirled my phone at the keyboard to represent my state of mind. If you're wondering why you can see discrete keys instead of just a blurry spiral, it's because the keys actually blink faster than I can see (did a slowmo of my keyboard), so on a slow exposure each of these blinks is recorded, breaking up the blur into pieces.

[image: Late Night Work]

Answer (score 18):

## Picasso in Four Dimensions

[image: Picasso in Four Dimensions]

Shot through a cascading sheet of water, using the water rather than the lens to blur and distort the model. (Honestly never thought I'd actually get to use this for anything other than having a little fun experimenting in the back yard.)

Nikon D300; Nikkor 70-300mm @ 145mm; 1/125sec; F7.1; ISO 200

January 30, 2011; Knoxville, TN

Answer (score 17):

[image: London bus]
London bus
Panasonic lumix Gx10. F3.5 1/10th second. ISO 3200 
February 10th 2018.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

**Carving Streets**

March 11, 2021, Boston, Massachusetts

Canon EOS 7d Mark II
Tamron SP 24-70mm
70 mm
f/5
1/6s
ISO 125

Captured this on the first warm day in Boston, reflects how fast I have felt the school year has passed

Answer (score 10):

[image: Church of Fire Dancer]

Church of Fire Dancer

Camera: Canon A1.

Film: 35mm, Black & White, Unknown.

Print: Full frame on 8"x 10" Silver gelatin paper, Lith Print. (*Developed in Highly diluted lithography chemicals*.)

Scanned on a crappy old dusty scanner. No digital manipulation other then some spotting of dust from said scanner.

Answer (score 7):

### Swirly

[image]

Oulu, Finland, 2021-01-24

Motorola Moto G7 phone camera. f/2.2, shutter speed 1/25, ISO 550.

Post-processing: Cropped a bit and added contrast.

Answer (score 6):

**Eye of the Blur** - Quito, Ecuador (2007)

[image: Eye of The Blur]

Pentax K10D + DA 50-200mm F/4-5.6 @ 138mm - ISO 100 F/5.6 1/6s

Captured by [Itai Danan](https://www.neoluminance.com/) and published with: Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 (CC BY-SA 4.0) with attribution required.

Answer (score 6):

### Lightning Storm

**Date Taken**: 2021-03-12 @ 8:49PM

**Location**: The balcony of my apartment near Sydney, Australia

**Camera**: Nikon D3200

**Lens**: AF-S DX NIKKOR 35mm f/1.8G

**Settings**: ISO1600, 1/80 sec, f/1.8, 35mm

[image: Lightning Storm]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

First of July 1986 in Ottawa.

Olympus OM2 camera, Kodak ISO-400 film, no tripod.
Scanned from print, no other processing.

I was expecting to get garbage, but the long exposure improved what was actually there.

Comment: Are you required to wear white polos to Canada Day?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, lately, people tend to wear white and red on Canada Day (the flag's colours), but back then, perhaps that was simply a common fashion for any day.

Answer (score 5):

### mmidnight snacking

Los Gatos, CA, April 14th 10:22PM

Nikon D500, Nikkor AF-S DX 18-140mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR,

f/11, 0.5 secs, ISO-1100

[image]

Answer (score 5):

"Distressed Kitchen", a kitchen in Germany, 2020-01-01, Sony DSC-R1, f/5.0, 8s, varied focal length, ISO160

[image: Distressed Kitchen]

Answer (score 4):

### In Reflection

[image]

Brightly-lit shop windows & illuminated trees, taken in reflection through a brass plaque [shingle] on a store on the opposite side of the street.

One of my very early forays: November 2016, Tenerife - Nikon D5500 kit lens 18-55mm @55mm f/5.6 1/125s ISO 8000 (lot of noise clean-up:)

Answer (score 4):

### Lost My Glasses

[image]

March 2021, Oulu.

Agfa Silette Vario - Color Agnar 45mm f/2.8 - Ilford HP5+ 400 (pushed to 800 with Ilfosol 3 developer)

Shot at f/2.8, shutter speed probably 1/50. Wasn't sure how close the lens was able to focus, and misjudged it a bit (there's just an 'm' (for "macro", I suppose) at the close end of the focusing ring). It's a viewfinder camera, so you can't see through the lens. Just a quick snap at the end of the roll. There are some water spots, but since only a handful of frames were affected, I didn't bother cleaning them and rescanning.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Bulls-Eye]

Bulls-Eye (*Dartboard*)

**Camera:** Zero Image 4x5 Pinhole, with a medium format film back.

**Film:** Black & White, Unknown.

**Print:** Full frame on 8"x 10"  Silver gelatin paper, Lith Print. (*Developed in Highly diluted lithography chemicals*.)

*Scanned on a crappy old dusty scanner. No digital manipulation other then some spotting of dust from said scanner.*

Answer (score 4):

### Warp Walker

[image: 1]

Photo taken with a Coolpix W300, no lens info recorded on October 19, 2020 in Marshfield Vermont.  Flashes annoy horses, so photos may blur in a lightly-lit barn.  The horse is a very patient Tennessee Walker.

Answer (score 3):

### Crow Chasing Hawk

Los Gatos, CA, April 4th 2021

Nikon D500, Nikkor AF-S DX 18-140mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR,

f/8, 1/125 secs, ISO-100

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Catadioptric Sun Filtering Through Trees

- Autumn afternoon in 2020
- Nikon D3100; 500mm Catadioptric lens with fixed f/8; 1/2000 at ISO 800

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**"To the Fire ...."**

[image]

Somewhat higher resolution version (Facebook page) [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=5278326755574110&set=a.5099297423477045)

Answer (score 1):

**Entering 28th St**
Location: 28th St uptown platform on the IRT Lexington Avenue Line of the NYC Subway.
Date: March 15, 2021 around 7:30 PM.
Pixel 4 camera, ƒ/1.73 1/44 4.38mm ISO55 and then cropped.

I noticed that the track at this station was level enough that the lines in the tiles aligned with the train's movement (the tiles are usually laid true level, rather than being level with a sloping track).

[image]